# SQLServer 2016 - BCP Generates empty files when using a temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, bcp

I was tasked to optimize the following SP in SQLServer 2016, it generates a folder and inside it, it generates .txt files from the data extracted, the SP is the following.

```
USE [postilion_office]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ath_backUp_EjAtm]    Script Date: 23/02/2021 15:24:38 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ath_backUp_EjAtm] @date_ini DATETIME, @date_top DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

  -- Definicion de variables
  DECLARE @term_id  CHAR(8)
  
  DECLARE @date_fin DATETIME
  
  DECLARE @fldr_path VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @file_path VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @fldr_cmmd VARCHAR(200)
  DECLARE @cmmd_fdlt VARCHAR(900)
  DECLARE @cmmd_fzip VARCHAR(900)
  
  DECLARE @date_vini VARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @date_vfin VARCHAR(10)
  DECLARE @date_vtxt VARCHAR(10)
  
  DECLARE @bcp_ejInfo VARCHAR(2000)
  
  -- Inicio fechas de proceso
  SET @date_fin = @date_ini + 1
  
  WHILE (@date_fin <= @date_top)
  BEGIN
    
    -- Define variables de texto para las fechas empleadas
    SET @date_vini = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date_ini, 101)
    SET @date_vfin = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date_fin, 101)
    SET @date_vtxt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date_ini, 112)
    
    -- Crea carpeta de almacenamiento para la fecha
    SET  @fldr_path = 'Y:\temp\Tira\' + @date_vtxt
    SET  @fldr_cmmd = 'mkdir ' + @fldr_path
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @fldr_cmmd, no_output
    
    -- Cursor de terminales con trasmision para la fecha
    DECLARE ejTerm_cursor CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT DISTINCT term_id
      FROM   postilion_office.dbo.post_term_ej_activity_exception WITH (NOLOCK)
      WHERE  insert_date_time between @date_ini and @date_fin 
      ORDER  BY term_id
    
    OPEN ejTerm_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ejTerm_cursor INTO @term_id
    
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
      -- Construye sentencia de consulta para la tira diaria por cajero y ejecuta el export a un archivo plano
      SET  @bcp_ejInfo = 'bcp "select * from (select tt.term_ej_activity_id,tt.term_id,tt.insert_date_time,tt.date_time,tt.activity from postilion_office.dbo.post_term_ej_activity_exception tt with (nolock)) t where insert_date_time between ''' + @date_vini + ''' and ''' + @date_vfin + ''' and term_id = ''' + @term_id + ''' order by term_ej_activity_id" queryout "' + @fldr_path + '\' + @term_id + '_' + @date_vtxt + '.txt" -c -T -t''##'' -r''&&'''
      print @bcp_ejInfo
      EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_ejInfo, no_output
      
      -- Comprime el archivo de tira generado
      SET  @file_path = '"' + @fldr_path + '\' + @term_id + '_' + @date_vtxt + '.txt"'
      SET  @cmmd_fzip = 'gzip -fNq ' + @file_path
      EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmmd_fzip, no_output
      
      FETCH NEXT FROM ejTerm_cursor INTO @term_id
    END 
    
    CLOSE ejTerm_cursor
    DEALLOCATE ejTerm_cursor
    
    -- Incrementa los valores de fechas para los criterios de consulta
    SET @date_ini = @date_ini + 1
    SET @date_fin = @date_ini + 1
  END
END
```

So this is my optimized solution ( I created a temp table `#TempData` and insert all the data needed to generate the .txt files in it, then I apply an Index to order the data, Finally I changed the BCP query to now get the data from the temp table `#TempData`, the code is as follows:

```
USE [postilion_office]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ath_backUp_EjAtm]    Script Date: 16/02/2021 11:35:41 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ath_backUp_EjAtm] @date_ini DATETIME, @date_top DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

  -- Definicion de variables
  DECLARE @term_id  CHAR(8)
  
  DECLARE @date_fin DATETIME
  
  DECLARE @fldr_path VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @file_path VARCHAR(100)
  DECLARE @fldr_cmmd VARCHAR(200)
  DECLARE @cmmd_fdlt VARCHAR(900)
  DECLARE @cmmd_fzip VARCHAR(900)
  DECLARE @date_vtxt VARCHAR(10)
  
  DECLARE @bcp_ejInfo VARCHAR(2000)
  
  -- Inicio fechas de proceso
  SET @date_fin = @date_ini + 1

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempData

  -------------------------------------------------------------------------------xxx
  CREATE TABLE #TempData
    (
    [term_ej_activity_id] [bigint],
    [term_id] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [insert_date_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [date_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [activity] [varchar](max) NOT NULL)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------xxx
  WHILE (@date_fin <= @date_top)
  BEGIN
    
    

    -- Define variables de texto para las fechas empleadas
    SET @date_vtxt = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @date_ini, 112)
   
    truncate table #TempData
       
      INSERT INTO #TempData
      select tt.term_ej_activity_id,tt.term_id,tt.insert_date_time,tt.date_time,tt.activity 
      from postilion_office.dbo.post_term_ej_activity_exception tt with (nolock) 
      where insert_date_time between @date_ini and @date_fin

      DROP INDEX IF EXISTS TempTableindex
        ON #TempData

      CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX TempTableindex ON #TempData ([term_id]);

     

    -- Crea carpeta de almacenamiento para la fecha
    SET  @fldr_path = 'Y:\temp\Tira\' + @date_vtxt
    SET  @fldr_cmmd = 'mkdir ' + @fldr_path
    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @fldr_cmmd, no_output
    
    -- Cursor de terminales con trasmision para la fecha
    DECLARE ejTerm_cursor CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT DISTINCT term_id
      FROM   #TempData
      WHERE  insert_date_time between @date_ini and @date_fin 
      ORDER  BY term_id
    
    OPEN ejTerm_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM ejTerm_cursor INTO @term_id
    
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
      -- Construye sentencia de consulta para la tira diaria por cajero y ejecuta el export a un archivo plano
      SET  @bcp_ejInfo = 'bcp "select * from #TempData
      where term_id = ''' + @term_id + '''order by term_ej_activity_id" queryout "' + @fldr_path + '\' + @term_id + '_' + @date_vtxt + '.txt" -c -T -t''##'' -r''&&'''


      EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcp_ejInfo, no_output
      
      -- Comprime el archivo de tira generado
      SET  @file_path = '"' + @fldr_path + '\' + @term_id + '_' + @date_vtxt + '.txt"'
      SET  @cmmd_fzip = 'gzip -fNq ' + @file_path
      EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmmd_fzip, no_output
      
      FETCH NEXT FROM ejTerm_cursor INTO @term_id
    END 
    
    CLOSE ejTerm_cursor
    DEALLOCATE ejTerm_cursor
    
    -- Incrementa los valores de fechas para los criterios de consulta
    SET @date_ini = @date_ini + 1
    SET @date_fin = @date_ini + 1
  END

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempData

END
```

the problem is that my solution creates the folder and all the .txt files, but all of them are empty, I have made sure that the table `#TempData` contains data right before the BCP gets executed, I cant tell what I'm doing wrong since the unoptimized SP works perfectly.

I have tried changing the -c to -w but still nothing, please help, I don't know what else to do.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `#` temp tables are local to the session, you need `##` for a global table. But you probably shouldn't be doing this in SQL, Powershell is much better placed for this kind of thing. You also have an injection risk here, with all those bcp parameters

Comment: thank you very much! that resolved the issue, but I got a question, I tried my same solution but I removed all the `#` from the temp table `#TempData` but it didn't worked either, why ?

Comment: removing the # from the temptable creates a permanent table called TempData - similar to a staging table. Very different from #TempTable or ##Temptable

Comment: In your second proc, ath_backUp_EjAtm, you have a line break in the middle of the command line, so the command getting executed is effectively `bcp "select * from #TempData`

Comment: @Harry yeah, why that didn't work either ? maybe it was because of what AlwaysLearning Said, I dont remember if I tried removing the # before or after realizing that the line break was messing my query